# Start Car When Remote Battery Is Dead

Tags: mazda

I have a `2013 Mazda CX-5` and the battery in my "dongle" has died.  I live 45 miles from the closest dealer and I need to drive the vehicle.  Is there a way to start the vehicle even though the battery in the dongle is dead?

(It is a push to start and once the dongle is detected the push to start button turns green and you push it to start.  Since the battery is dead in the dongle the push to start button never turns green.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://youtu.be/uQkNqu4DCvU)

Comment: Don't you have a second dongle?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Nice! Someone thought of a backup. Putting the back of the fob against the start button makes me wonder if that's NFC wireless stuff...Maybe a smartphone could act as the key too.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5fKMTqfki4 This one might save the trip to the dealer for replacing the battery, if it's the same fob (and you can find the right battery locally).

Comment: @Hobbes if the second dongle has a battery that is equally old, chances are it is dead too. The true solution is what Paulster2 found. The same solution works in many cars, e.g. in my 2016 Toyota RAV4 Hybrid you can also start the car in the same way using a dead fob. However, if the fob becomes dead during wintertime, chances are the mechanical door lock is frozen.

Comment: @Hobbes - yes, we have 2 fobs, however the one with the working battery was in my pocket 60 miles away and the wife was trying to get to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Steps listed here as taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/uQkNqu4DCvU)

- With the remote in hand, remove the auxiliary key from the fob
- Use the auxiliary key to unlock the driver's side door
- Once inside the vehicle, depress the brake pedal (auto tranny) or depress the clutch pedal (manual tranny)
- Check that the green start indicator light is blinking
- Touch the push button start using the back side of the fob while the green indicator light flashes
- Push the push button start when the light indicator turns solid green to start the engine
- After the engine starts, let it idle for about 10 seconds

These procedures should work for 13-14 Mazda CX-5.